# Accesing to specific attribute into rest1-v1 threw versionone.sdk.Api in C#

Tags: c#, versionone

I'm trying to access to a specific value stored in the rest1-v1 api of versionOne.

I can acces to it typing the whole adress into my favorite navigator

```
rest-1.v1/Data/Actual?sel=Date,Value&where=Workitem.ID='Story:114192'
```

which returns:

```
<Assets total="1" pageSize="2147483647" pageStart="0">
    <Asset href="/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Actual/158630" id="Actual:158630">
        <Attribute name="Date">2014-10-23</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="Value">40</Attribute>
    </Asset>
</Assets>
```

What I would like to do, is to access to the attribute "Value" listed above but threw the versionone.sdk.ApiClient.

I did all the stuff about connector (meta and data), but I really do not figure out how to make my query to return this value stored into this API.

I hope I am clear enough,

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        V1APIConnector dataConnector = new V1APIConnector("YourVersionOne/rest-1.v1/","username", "password");
        V1APIConnector metaConnector = new V1APIConnector("YourVersionOne/meta.v1/");

        IMetaModel metaModel = new MetaModel(metaConnector);
        IServices services = new Services(metaModel, dataConnector);
        IAssetType actualType = metaModel.GetAssetType("Actual");

        IAttributeDefinition dateAttribute = actualType.GetAttributeDefinition("Date");
        IAttributeDefinition valueAttribute = actualType.GetAttributeDefinition("Value");
        IAttributeDefinition workitemAttribute = actualType.GetAttributeDefinition("Workitem");
        Query query = new Query(actualType);

        query.Selection.Add(dateAttribute);
        query.Selection.Add(valueAttribute);

        FilterTerm term = new FilterTerm(workitemAttribute);
        term.Equal("Story:114192");
        query.Filter = term;

        QueryResult result = services.Retrieve(query);
```

BTW, you didn't need Workitem.ID in your url query.  Workitem is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the trick ! I was getting mad trying things and things